# file uploading with Multer in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I am using [Multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) version 1.2.0, with  nodejs, whenever i am trying to upload an image in base64 getting error --Error: Field value too long
**Error**

```
Error: Field value too long
at makeError (C:\xampp\htdocs\sitename\node_modules\multer\lib\make-error.js:12:13)
at abortWithCode (C:\xampp\htdocs\sitename\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:77:22)
at Busboy.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\sitename\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:83:34)
at Busboy.emit (events.js:118:17)
at Busboy.emit (C:\xampp\htdocs\sitename\node_modules\multer\node_modules\busboy\lib\main.js:31:35)
at PartStream.onEnd (C:\xampp\htdocs\sitename\node_modules\multer\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:261:15)
at PartStream.emit (events.js:129:20)
at Dicer.onPart (C:\xampp\htdocs\sitename\node_modules\multer\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:120:13)
at Dicer.emit (events.js:107:17)
at Dicer.emit (C:\xampp\htdocs\sitename\node_modules\multer\node_modules\busboy\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:80:35)
```

**Code:**

```
var multer  = require('multer');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './photos')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
    }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).any()

app.post('/admin/uploadpicture', upload, function(req, res) {
    res.send('Test');
});
```

Not able to understand where i am missing, kindly suggest anything.
   Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried setting `upload.single('field')` instead of `upload` in your /admin/uploadpicture route?

Comment: I have to upload four images at a time that's why I am using
var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).any()

Answer (score 8):

Increase the field data limit using the limits option:

```
multer({
  limits: { fieldSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024 }
})
```

[refer link](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/436#issuecomment-269545650)

Answer (score 0):

you can use upload.array('field') to upload as many files as you want.

Answer (score 0):

if after adding the limits to multer you are still seeing this issue, it is likely because you are attempting to upload the same image multiple times and it is having trouble over riding the previous image. i've uploaded a new pic